# page-break-inside:avoid blank page issue in IE 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

I have a lot of tables on a page with variable amounts of content in them. 
I am trying to use `page-break-inside: avoid`; so that each table section is 
not broken over 2 pages.

It is working in all browser but not in IE 10. a blank page gets added 
on print-preview/print

how i remove this extra blank page.

Following link wiil show my test page and on print preview you see a blank page on page no 2

http://ourclientwebsites.com/Test.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this time the HTML will show:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530844(v=vs.85).aspx says re page-break-before:

> "This property applies when printing the document. This property does
>   not apply to the br or hr elements."

So if you applied your page break to a `<BR>`
element as in:

```
<BR style="page-break-before:always">
```

Just apply it to a `<P>` element instead and it will work:

```
<P style="page-break-before:always"></P>
```

Comment: The question is about page breaks in the printed output, more specifically in the print preview.

Answer (score 0):

IE10 Is doing the exact same thing for me.  Unfortunately the only fix I have been able to find is to use Compatibility Mode.  Hopefully this is something that will be fixed in future updates.